# Deepviews displaying incorrect text when app is already downloaded using Branch

Tags: ionic-framework, branch.io

So I discovered an issue on iOS today after implementing on my devices earlier this week. I generated a new Deepviews template using the BranchIo dashboard, it looks great except the text at the bottom of the webpage is misleading if the user has the app installed already as it shows "Get The App" instead of (what it's supposed to) "Open The App"

Looking at the template html generated from the DeepView:

`<a href="{{action}}" class="cta-button text-light{{#unless app.og_image_url}} cta-button--no-app-icon{{/unless}}{{#if no_data}} cta-button--no-app-icon{{/if}}">{{#if has_app}}Open{{else}}Get{{/if}} The App</a>`

I'm not quite sure how to debug this issue as I set up the config on my dashboard:

[image]

While my `config.xml` has the following information:

```
<branch-config>
    <branch-key value="---MY KEY---" />
    <uri-scheme value="releasehub" />
    <link-domain value="releasehub.app.link" />
    <ios-team-release value="3MWVVWCS4Y" />
</branch-config>
<plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^3.1.6" />
```

I made a short video showing how the Deepviews displays **Get the App** even though the app is installed:

https://streamable.com/fa71n

What am I missing? Thanks!

**EDIT after running validation script**

I followed the Ionic Branch installation instructions found on the GitHub page, what else do I need to do? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Active deepviews should only show when the app is not installed (or when direct deep linking doesn't work, like in the Facebook webview), and pause on the deepview page. These let the user preview the content, ultimately deciding if they want to install the app. The user must click the call-to-action of Get The App in order to be sent to the appropriate App or Play Store page. Can you make sure your Universal link is enabled by running the validator script here?: https://docs.branch.io/resources/validation-tools/#universal-link-validator

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, I ran the script and edited my original post with a screenshot of the results. Looks like "Enable Universal Links"" is correctly checked. What am I missing?

Comment: I’d follow these->
https://docs.branch.io/apps/ios/#configure-bundle-identifier
https://docs.branch.io/apps/ios/#configure-entitlements